# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLImageElement

Tags: javascript, html, css

so this is the issue i have on my website

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of null at HTMLImageElement.
```

and this is my code

> https://jsfiddle.net/kikiZ/59ej2g8m/

maybe there's another solution to fix this problem because i have looking on the other website but still didn't find the answer

and the problem on this code

```
        <script>

        var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
        var nav = document.getElementById('nav');
        var exit = document.getElementById('exit');

        menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
            nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
            e.preventDefault();
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: change `document.getElementById('nav');` to `document.querySelector('nav');`

Comment: Do that @DominikMatis says, or give your nav an `id` of "nav" like this. `<nav id="nav">`

Comment: You are asking for `getElementById('nav')` but you didn't provide id on `<nav>` tag. It should be `<nav id="nav">`

Comment: ok thx for the suggestion now i have change it like dominik says but now my navigation bar should show the home service etc and now nothing tho show am i wrong or there's something i miss it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For fixing the toggle button on small screens**

the solution:
paste this code instead of your Javascript code and try to read it:

```
var menu = document.getElementById('menu');
var nav = document.querySelector('nav ul');
var exit = document.getElementById('exit');

menu.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    nav.classList.toggle('hide-mobile');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Explain:**

***FIRST:***

If you want to use `classlist` method, then you should have a class inside the HTML  `<nav>` tag.
what you're doing is that you're searching for a class inside nothing, because what  `getElementById('')` does is that it searches inside the **DOM** (the HTML file) for an Id with the name that matches the passed argument; mean in your case:
`getElementById('nav')` : it's searching for an #Id with the name of nav but you don't have.
So you have to decide:
you may use `getElementById('')` but you need to add an id with the name of nav to your `<nav>` tag; so `<nav id="nav">`.

or you may use `document.querySelector('nav')` instead of `document.getElementById('nav')`.

***SECOND***

after fixing the first problem you'll see another one and it's that your toggle button on small screens is not working.
That's because you're toggling the "hide-mobile" class on the `<nav>` and you don't want that, you want to toggle that class on the `<ul>` element because it's the element that contains the "hide-mobile" class by default.

Comment: the second issue is right sam, so how to solve the second issue

Comment: Like I just said, replace your Javascript code with the code which I wrote for you, glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have any element with id "nav".

Change document.getElementById('nav'); to document.querySelector('nav') or add id nav to element nav